# Find all values of a and b for which the following system has non-trivial solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble with this Linear Algebra problem and I don't seem to find any similar problems on this site. 
Just a short description or a small hint is highly appreciated.

***Find all values of a and b for which the following system has non-trivial solutions.***

```
                               ax + 2y = 0 
                               x − by = 0
```

Comment: Theae are two equations representing straight  lines though origin ,with ( x =0 , y=0 ) solution for *all* real values of a and b.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the first equation as saying that the vector $(x, y)$ is perpendicular to the vector $(a, 2)$; the second says that it's perpendicular to $(1, -b)$. Under what conditions on $a$ and $b$ is there a nonzero vector perpendicular to both of these?

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the $1^{st}$ equation by $b$, and the $2^{nd}$ equation by $2$ and add them to eliminate $y$: $(ab+2)x = 0 \Rightarrow ab+2 =0$ will yield non-trivial solution. For example, $a= 2, b = -1$ will do.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\begin{bmatrix}
a&2|0\\
1&-b|0\\
\end{bmatrix}\to \begin{bmatrix}
1&\frac{2}{a}|0\\
0&\frac{2}{a}+b|0\\
\end{bmatrix}$

We know that if $\frac{2}{a}+b=0$, there are infinitely many solutions, and if it is nonzero we can multiply this number by the additive inverse and continue the Gaussian algorithm to get that there are unique solutions.